# Segue Image to next ViewController (Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, segue, viewcontroller, swift5

Im trying to pass a Cached/Downloaded image to my display view controller that will be segued with different images. I can download the image and set it to a UIImageView on my current controller, or if I manually download an image that's UIImage i can segue it as I assign it to ImageStore variable. However when downloading my image through cache/download method, it arrives as UIImageView, how can I pass that as variable to another controller?

```
@IBOutlet weak var Image1: UIImageView!



var ImageStore: UIImage!//transfer image code to next screen
var ImageStore: UIImage!//transfer image code to next screen

@IBAction func Chart1Click(_ sender: Any)//chart 1
{
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Chart1", sender: nil)
}

@IBAction func Chart2Click(_ sender: Any)//chart 2
{
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Chart2", sender: nil)
}

@IBAction func Button(_ sender: Any)//download charts
{
    Image1.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "https://www.vedur.is/photos/flugkort/PGDE14_EGRR_0000.png"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
 //assing the Image1 to ImageStore ??

//more downloaded here
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if (segue.identifier == "Chart1")
    {
        let destinationViewController = segue.destination as! ChartAController
        destinationViewController.TransferImage = ImageStore
        print("Chart 1 Segue")
    }
    if (segue.identifier == "Chart2")
    {
        let destinationViewController = segue.destination as! ChartAController
        destinationViewController.TransferImage = ImageStore2
        print("Chart 2 Segue")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just send

```
ImageStore.image
```

It should solve the issue. If you want to send image instead of imageView.

Comment: And how do I assign my Image1 to ImageStore? Or download the image to an empty UIImageView variable?